# How to design a expandable block with amount at right side in Omnistudio flex card

Tags: omnistudio

I am trying to design something like below in flex card:

[image]

Originally this is just a expandable block with a title, but we need to add a total value at the right side and in the above screenshot.

I was thinking of structuring something like this:
[image]

Which I have used a parent block and two children blocks. The expandable one is on the left side.

But this left one big issue is, the expandable block when expanded will only take the left side inside of the whole window, which I cannot resolve.

Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I can think of.

Caution : This is very specific to form factor of the device, where the spaces needs to be calculated and added inbetween words.

If you can somehow build your JSON and include spaces in you title node. Something like this:

```
{
    "savingtitle" : "Saving                                                                                                               $224,759",
    "displayText" : "I will be displayed inside"
}
```

And then use custom css option, target the span tag and button element of the flexcard and change the background colour of button and add `white-space: pre;` for span tag. Then it should display similar to what is needed.

css:

```
runtime_omnistudio_flexcards-block span[class="slds-text-heading_small blockLabel label-color-onexpand"] {
    white-space: pre;
}

runtime_omnistudio_flexcards-block span[class="slds-text-heading_small blockLabel"] {
    white-space: pre;
}
runtime_omnistudio_flexcards-block button[class="slds-button slds-p-horizontal_x-small"] {
    width: 100%;
    background: var(--slds-g-color-neutral-base-95, var(--lwc-colorBackground,rgb(243, 243, 243)));
}
```

NOTE: Make sure to add custom css as global.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Solution 2:**

Create a flexcard, and have two elements at top with grid as 9 - 3,

The first one is a dummy element which is just there to hold space, the second one can hold your amount field.
And use css to place your amount field on top of accordian.

Something like this.

```
    {
        "savingtitle" : "Saving",
        "displayText" : "I will be displayed inside",
        "amount" : "$223,4758"
    }
```

Custom css:

```
runtime_omnistudio_flexcards-block span[class="slds-text-heading_small blockLabel label-color-onexpand"] {
    white-space: pre;
}

runtime_omnistudio_flexcards-block span[class="slds-text-heading_small blockLabel"] {
    white-space: pre;
}
runtime_omnistudio_flexcards-block button[class="slds-button slds-p-horizontal_x-small"] {
    width: 100%;
    background: var(--slds-g-color-neutral-base-95, var(--lwc-colorBackground,rgb(243, 243, 243)));
}

.customPosition {
position: relative;
top: 35px;
z-index: 20;
}
```

[image]

This is the JSON for the export of my component.

```
{
"useVlocityTriggers": true,
"status": "Complete",
"processMultiple": true,
"primaryDataPackType": "FlexCard",
"primaryDataPackKey": "5ef63961aae8528598ac05691dacb966",
"maxDepth": -1,
"isChunked": false,
"ignoreAllErrors": false,
"forceQueueable": false,
"forceOldDataModel": null,
"dataPacks": [
    {
    "VlocityPrimarySourceId": "0ko2w000000k9xRAAQ",
    "VlocityPreviousPageKey": null,
    "VlocityMultiPackParentKey": null,
    "VlocityDepthFromPrimary": 0,
    "VlocityDataPackType": "FlexCard",
    "VlocityDataPackStatus": "Success",
    "VlocityDataPackRelationshipType": "Primary",
    "VlocityDataPackRecords": [],
    "VlocityDataPackParents": [],
    "VlocityDataPackName": "FlexCardAccordionDetailsRight",
    "VlocityDataPackMessage": null,
    "VlocityDataPackLabel": "FlexCard",
    "VlocityDataPackKey": "5ef63961aae8528598ac05691dacb966",
    "VlocityDataPackIsNotSupported": false,
    "VlocityDataPackIsIncluded": true,
    "VlocityDataPackData": {
        "Id": "0ko2w000000k9xRAAQ",
        "VlocityDataPackRelationshipType": "Primary",
        "VlocityDataPackLabel": "FlexCard",
        "OmniUiCard": [
        {
            "Description": "",
            "AuthorName": "Salesforce",
            "OmniUiCardKey": "FlexCardAccordionDetailsRight/Salesforce/1.0",
            "OverrideKey": "",
            "IsActive": true,
            "DataSourceConfig": "{\"dataSource\":{\"type\":\"Custom\",\"value\":{\"dsDelay\":\"\",\"body\":\"{\\n\\\"savingtitle\\\" : \\\"Saving\\\",\\n\\\"displayText\\\" : \\\"I will be displayed inside\\\",\\n\\\"amount\\\" : \\\"$223,4758\\\"\\n}\",\"resultVar\":\"\"},\"orderBy\":{\"name\":\"\",\"isReverse\":\"\"},\"contextVariables\":[]}}",
            "VlocityDataPackType": "SObject",
            "SampleDataSourceResponse": "{\"savingtitle\":\"Saving\",\"displayText\":\"I will be displayed inside\",\"amount\":\"$223,4758\"}",
            "ClonedFromOmniUiCardKey": "",
            "CurrencyIsoCode": "INR",
            "VersionNumber": 1,
            "Namespace": "",
            "Name": "FlexCardAccordionDetailsRight",
            "IsTrackingEnabled": false,
            "VlocityRecordSObjectType": "OmniUiCard",
            "VlocityRecordSourceKey": "VlocityRecordSourceKey:0ko2w000000k9xRAAQ",
            "PropertySetConfig": "{\"states\":[{\"fields\":[],\"conditions\":{\"id\":\"state-condition-object\",\"isParent\":true,\"group\":[]},\"definedActions\":{\"actions\":[]},\"name\":\"Active\",\"isSmartAction\":false,\"smartAction\":{},\"styleObject\":{\"padding\":[{\"type\":\"around\",\"size\":\"x-small\"}],\"margin\":[{\"type\":\"bottom\",\"size\":\"x-small\"}],\"container\":{\"class\":\"slds-card\"},\"size\":{\"isResponsive\":false,\"default\":\"12\"},\"sizeClass\":\"slds-size_12-of-12\",\"class\":\"slds-card slds-p-around_x-small slds-m-bottom_x-small\"},\"components\":{\"layer-0\":{\"children\":[{\"name\":\"Field\",\"element\":\"outputField\",\"size\":{\"isResponsive\":false,\"default\":\"9\"},\"stateIndex\":0,\"class\":\"slds-col \",\"property\":{\"placeholder\":\"\",\"record\":\"{record}\",\"type\":\"text\",\"card\":\"{card}\"},\"type\":\"element\",\"styleObject\":{\"sizeClass\":\"slds-size_9-of-12 \",\"size\":{\"isResponsive\":false,\"default\":\"9\"}},\"elementLabel\":\"Field-1\"},{\"name\":\"Field\",\"element\":\"outputField\",\"size\":{\"isResponsive\":false,\"default\":\"3\"},\"stateIndex\":0,\"class\":\"slds-col \",\"property\":{\"placeholder\":\"\",\"record\":\"{record}\",\"type\":\"text\",\"card\":\"{card}\",\"label\":\"{amount}\"},\"type\":\"element\",\"styleObject\":{\"sizeClass\":\"slds-size_3-of-12 \",\"size\":{\"isResponsive\":false,\"default\":\"3\"},\"padding\":[],\"margin\":[],\"background\":{\"color\":\"\",\"image\":\"\",\"size\":\"\",\"repeat\":\"\",\"position\":\"\"},\"container\":{\"class\":\"customPosition\"},\"border\":{\"type\":\"\",\"width\":\"\",\"color\":\"\",\"radius\":\"\",\"style\":\"\"},\"elementStyleProperties\":{},\"text\":{\"align\":\"right\",\"color\":\"\"},\"inlineStyle\":\"\",\"class\":\"slds-text-align_right customPosition \",\"style\":\"      \\n         \"},\"elementLabel\":\"Field-0\",\"styleObjects\":[{\"key\":0,\"conditions\":\"default\",\"styleObject\":{\"sizeClass\":\"slds-size_3-of-12 \",\"size\":{\"isResponsive\":false,\"default\":\"3\"},\"padding\":[],\"margin\":[],\"background\":{\"color\":\"\",\"image\":\"\",\"size\":\"\",\"repeat\":\"\",\"position\":\"\"},\"container\":{\"class\":\"customPosition\"},\"border\":{\"type\":\"\",\"width\":\"\",\"color\":\"\",\"radius\":\"\",\"style\":\"\"},\"elementStyleProperties\":{},\"text\":{\"align\":\"right\",\"color\":\"\"},\"inlineStyle\":\"\",\"class\":\"slds-text-align_right customPosition \",\"style\":\"      \\n         \"},\"label\":\"Default\",\"name\":\"Default\",\"conditionString\":\"\",\"draggable\":false}]},{\"name\":\"Block\",\"element\":\"block\",\"size\":{\"isResponsive\":false,\"default\":\"12\"},\"stateIndex\":0,\"class\":\"slds-col \",\"property\":{\"label\":\"\\\\{savingtitle}\",\"collapsible\":true,\"record\":\"{record}\",\"collapsedByDefault\":true,\"card\":\"{card}\"},\"type\":\"block\",\"styleObject\":{\"padding\":[{\"type\":\"around\",\"size\":\"x-small\"}],\"class\":\"slds-p-around_x-small\",\"sizeClass\":\"slds-size_12-of-12\"},\"children\":[{\"key\":\"element_element_block_2_0_outputField_0_0\",\"name\":\"displayText\",\"element\":\"outputField\",\"size\":{\"isResponsive\":false,\"default\":\"10\"},\"stateIndex\":0,\"class\":\"slds-col \",\"property\":{\"placeholder\":\"output\",\"record\":\"{record}\",\"fieldName\":\"displayText\",\"label\":\"Label For Inside Text\",\"card\":\"{card}\",\"type\":\"text\"},\"type\":\"field\",\"styleObject\":{\"sizeClass\":\"slds-size_10-of-12 \",\"size\":{\"isResponsive\":false,\"default\":\"10\"}},\"parentElementKey\":\"element_block_2_0\",\"elementLabel\":\"savingBlock-displayText-0\"}],\"elementLabel\":\"savingBlock\",\"userUpdatedElementLabel\":true}]}},\"childCards\":[],\"actions\":[],\"omniscripts\":[],\"documents\":[]}],\"dataSource\":{\"type\":\"Custom\",\"value\":{\"dsDelay\":\"\",\"body\":\"{\\n\\\"savingtitle\\\" : \\\"Saving\\\",\\n\\\"displayText\\\" : \\\"I will be displayed inside\\\",\\n\\\"amount\\\" : \\\"$223,4758\\\"\\n}\",\"resultVar\":\"\"},\"orderBy\":{\"name\":\"\",\"isReverse\":\"\"},\"contextVariables\":[]},\"title\":\"FlexCardAccordionDetailsRight\",\"enableLwc\":true,\"isFlex\":true,\"theme\":\"slds\",\"selectableMode\":\"Multi\",\"globalCSS\":true,\"xmlObject\":{\"targetConfigs\":\"PHRhcmdldENvbmZpZyB0YXJnZXRzPSJsaWdodG5pbmdfX0FwcFBhZ2UiPgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDxwcm9wZXJ0eSBuYW1lPSJkZWJ1ZyIgdHlwZT0iQm9vbGVhbiIvPgogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDxwcm9wZXJ0eSBuYW1lPSJyZWNvcmRJZCIgdHlwZT0iU3RyaW5nIi8+CiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8L3RhcmdldENvbmZpZz4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDx0YXJnZXRDb25maWcgdGFyZ2V0cz0ibGlnaHRuaW5nX19SZWNvcmRQYWdlIj4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8cHJvcGVydHkgbmFtZT0iZGVidWciIHR5cGU9IkJvb2xlYW4iLz4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDwvdGFyZ2V0Q29uZmlnPg==\",\"targets\":{\"target\":[\"lightning__RecordPage\",\"lightning__AppPage\",\"lightning__HomePage\"]},\"apiVersion\":51,\"masterLabel\":\"FlexCardAccordionDetailsRight\",\"description\":\"\",\"runtimeNamespace\":\"\",\"isExposed\":false},\"xmlJson\":[{\"@attributes\":{\"targets\":\"lightning__AppPage\"},\"property\":[{\"@attributes\":{\"name\":\"debug\",\"type\":\"Boolean\"}},{\"@attributes\":{\"name\":\"recordId\",\"type\":\"String\"}}]},{\"@attributes\":{\"targets\":\"lightning__RecordPage\"},\"property\":[{\"@attributes\":{\"name\":\"debug\",\"type\":\"Boolean\"}}]}]}",
            "OmniUiCardType": "Parent",
            "Id": "0ko2w000000k9xRAAQ",
            "VlocityDataPackIsIncluded": true,
            "StylingConfiguration": "{\"customStyles\":\"runtime_%vlocity_namespace%_flexcards-block span[class=\\\"slds-text-heading_small blockLabel label-color-onexpand\\\"] {\\n    white-space: pre;\\n}\\n\\nruntime_%vlocity_namespace%_flexcards-block span[class=\\\"slds-text-heading_small blockLabel\\\"] {\\n    white-space: pre;\\n}\\nruntime_%vlocity_namespace%_flexcards-block button[class=\\\"slds-button slds-p-horizontal_x-small\\\"] {\\n    width: 100%;\\n    background: var(--slds-g-color-neutral-base-95, var(--lwc-colorBackground,rgb(243, 243, 243)));\\n}\\n\\n.customPosition {\\n  position: relative;\\n  top: 35px;\\n  z-index: 20;\\n}\"}",
            "UniqueName": "FlexCardAccordionDetailsRight_Salesforce_1"
        }
        ],
        "VlocityDataPackType": "FlexCard",
        "VlocityDataPackKey": "5ef63961aae8528598ac05691dacb966"
    },
    "VlocityDataPackAllRelationships": {},
    "DataPackAttachmentSize": 7917,
    "DataPackAttachmentParentId": "0nc2w000000k9w9AAA",
    "DataPackAttachmentId": "00P2w00000EocLLEAZ",
    "ActivationStatus": "Ready"
    }
],
"dataPackId": "0nc2w000000k9w9AAA",
"alreadyExportedKeys": [],
"name": "FlexCardAccordionDetailsRight",
"description": "",
"version": 1,
"Status": "Complete"
}
```

you can save it as JSON named `FlexCardAccordionDetailsRight.json` and should be good to import it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, the length of the amount can be dynamic so it might be hard to calculate how many spaces should be there. Also, this solution doesn't work for responsiveness.

Comment: Hi @LanceShi I added another solution , do let me know if that works for you. I can share the export separately. This should work for responsiveness too,